# where x whereRaw Qual a diferença?

Tags: laravel, query

Tentei ler na documentação do Laravel mas, não entendi direito a diferença. Tentei também buscar outros links mas, geralmente vejo tópicos em fóruns pedindo ajuda sobre o uso e não tem alguma explicação clara sobre o motivo do uso.

Afinal de contas pra que serve o whereRaw e quando utilizar em vez de utilizar where?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O `whereRaw()` é uma função do query builder do Laravel pra colocar o input como ele é na cláusula `where`.

Basicamente é uma função `where()`  cujos argumentos não serão processados antes de serem inseridos na query.

## Ex:

Essa query:

```
$Query = DB::table('some_table')->where('YEAR(date)', 'YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)');
```

Será convertida em:

```
SELECT * FROM `some_table` WHERE `YEAR(date)` = `YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)`
```

Enquanto essa query:

```
$Query = DB::table('some_table')->whereRaw('YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)');
```

será convertida em:

```
SELECT * FROM `some_table` WHERE YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
```